# What python web request library is most similar to an ajax xmlhttprequest?

Tags: python, ajax, xmlhttprequest, httpwebrequest

Im struggling to find a python libary that can send GET requests that isn't blocked  by my company's firewall.

From using vba on the company network I know that an xmlhttprequest works whereas a winhttprequest will be blocked by the company firewall.

So far I have tried libs such as 'requests' and 'urllib2' etc. But I have since had no luck. I have tried using proxy methods for each but It doesnt really seem like an option.

Is there any object in python that is similar to the basic xhr request? or is there way of calling it within python? As i know this wont be blocked by the firewall.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't it easier to get you it-dept to open the firewall for you?

Comment: According to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226074/simulating-ajax-post-call-using-python-requests) you can specify in the send-headers what type of request, but it's unclear whether that only works for the site or if that will work on the firewall side

Comment: G, Anderson I'll give it a go when back in the office, and opening up the firewall isn't really an option in this case.

Comment: No joy the with request as header, looks like it only matters for the website and not the user side