# How to input date range in html date-picker when scraping with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to input a custom date range in a html form to scrape the data for the given range. HTML code looks the following:

```
<div class="dateRange inlineblock datePickerBinder arial_11 lightgrayFont" 
     id="widgetFieldDateRange">03/19/2019 - 04/18/2019</div>
</div>
<input id="picker" type="hidden" value=" 03/19/2019 - 04/18/2019">
```

I've tried the following:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse as urlParse

url = 'https://www.investing.com/funds/lansforsakringar-global-indexnara-historical-data'
values = {'start':'01/18/2019','end':'04/18/2019'}

# pretend to be a chrome 47 browser on a windows 10 machine
headers = {
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept" : "text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
    "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest"
}

# encode values for the url
params = urlParse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")

# create the url
s = requests.Session()  
targetUrl = s.post(url=url, data=params, headers=headers)


# open the url
html = BeautifulSoup(targetUrl.content, "html.parser")

# read the response
print(html.prettify)
```

But when printing the response I see that the default date-range is set and that my custom date range has not been applied. How do I solve this problem?

Found this also, what i believe is the javascript that is posting the date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.siteData = {
                htmlDirection: 'ltr',
                decimalPoint: '.' || '.',
                thousandSep: ',' || ',',
                isEu : false,
                userLoggedIn: false,
                userHasPhoneRegistered: false,
                currencyPosition: 'left',
                datepicker: {
                    applyButton: 'Apply',
                    format: 'm/d/Y',
                    formatShort: 'm/d/y',
                    formatLong: 'm/d/Y',
                    formatSend: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    firstDay: '1',
                    dayNames: ["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],
                    monthNamesShort: ["Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "Jun.", "Jul.", "Aug.", "Sep.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec."],
                    monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
                    translations: {
                        custom: 'Custom dates',
                        start: 'Start Date',
                        end: 'End Date'
                    }
```

Comment: the data is populated from an ajax call to `https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax` with form-data in the request body. load the page in your browser, open your inspector, and then change the date. you'll see the POST to `https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax` with the correct request body

Comment: I see, but I do not quite understand the implication of this? Do I simulate the POST to https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax with my params?

Comment: yup, that's exactly what you'd do. then you can parse that response with beautifulsoup (because it comes back as html)

Comment: @wpercy I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226074/simulating-ajax-post-call-using-python-requests and I geuss it's this I will have to figure out in some way. meaning I can't make a GET request but have to make a POST request

Comment: put what query will edit the date-range, I'm not sure if this works?    values = {'widgetFieldDateRange':'01/18/2019 - 04/18/2019'}

Comment: nope, you're going to want to set the `st_date` and `end_date` keys in the form data that you submit

Comment: @wpercy having no success, script is updated in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help you click the calendar menu and input values using Selenium. There is an Ajax POST made by the page but I was unable to pass the right cookies (I think)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.investing.com/funds/lansforsakringar-global-indexnara-historical-data')
try:  #attempt to dismiss banners that could block later clicks
    WebDriverWait(d, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".closer"))).click()
    d.find_element_by_css_selector('.closer').click()
except:
    pass
d.find_element_by_id('widgetFieldDateRange').click() #show the date picker
sDate  = d.find_element_by_id('startDate') # set start date input element into variable
sDate.clear() #clear existing entry
sDate.send_keys('01/18/2019') #add custom entry
eDate = d.find_element_by_id('endDate') #repeat for end date
eDate.clear()
eDate.send_keys('04/18/2019')
d.find_element_by_id('applyBtn').click() #submit changes
```

Comment: I don't know how it works, but it sure works and that is amazing! Thank you so much for your time and help QHarr!

Comment: Can't thank you enough, you truly are the golden standard!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.investing.com/funds/lansforsakringar-global-indexnara-historical-data')
r = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('div', {'id':'widgetFieldDateRange'}).text
```

Output:

```
'03/18/2019 - 04/18/2019'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm not that familiar with selenium but I'm not really after printing the date-range but to modify it and apply a custom date-range so that I can scrape the results between various date-ranges.